# Hacer un DISTINCT solo en una columna?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2008

quiero hacer un DISTINCT pero que solo aplique en una columna porque consulto dos cosas, un ID y una imagen y solo quiero que me muestre una imagen de ese producto.

Trato de que me quede asi.

```
| producto | imagen         |
|----------|----------------|
| 1111     | 0x15A8SA9A.... |
| 1112     | 0x15A8SA9A.... |
| 1113     | 0x15A8SA9A.... |
```

Tengo mi tabla asi

```
Id -> int
producto -> int (relacionado con la tabla producto) 
imagen -> image
```

Intente de esta forma

```
select producto, imagen 
from imagenes 
where producto in (select producto from imagenes group by producto)
```

¿Que debo hacer? ¿Como hago un DISTINCT solo en la columna producto?

Estoy usando SQL SERVER 2008.

De antemano gracias por leer

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar el manejador de base de datos que estás usando editando la pregunta y colocando la etiqueta correspondiente: MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgresql ...? ¿Esperas sólo una fila por resultado o podrían ser varias filas? Ese aspecto no queda claro.

Answer (score 1):

#### Lo que haces

```
select producto, imagen 
from imagenes 
where producto in (select producto from imagenes group by producto)
```

En esta sentencia estas haciendo algo complicado :

```
select producto from imagenes group by producto
```

Agrupas los productos , de la tabla imágenes y los agrupas por producto. Lo que da entender que puede existir más de un producto con más de una imagen. En otro caso estás haciendo un `select * from imagenes`, simplemente.

```
 select producto, imagen 
 from imagenes 
 where producto in (select producto from imagenes group by producto)
```

Luego en la consulta , estas diciendo que si ese producto , existe en la propia tabla imágenes.

La consulta no la tienes correctamente montada.

#### Mi solución

> un ID y una imagen y solo quiero que me muestre una imagen de ese
>   producto.

Entonces solo necesitas por ejemplo :

```
SELECT imagen
FROM imagenes
WHERE producto = 1111
```

Asi obtienes la imagen del producto deseado.

Answer (score 0):

```
select producto, imagen 
from imagenes 
where producto in (select producto from imagenes group by producto)
```

El problema de esta query viene de que a pesar de que la subconsulta te devuelve valor distintos `(1111,1112,1113,etc)` la consulta general general sigue entrando en todos los valores por la siguiente razon, ya que indicas lo siguiente:

- Subconsulta: `(1111,1112,1113,1114)`
- Consulta general: *"selecciona todos los valores si el id_producto esta en la subconsulta"*. El error es que todos los valores de la tabla ya estan en la subsconsulta ya que a pesar de ser duplicado siguien cumpliendo el `WHERE``:

  - el producto 1111 con la primera imagen esta en  la subconsulta
  - el producto 1111 con la segunda imagen **tambien** esta en la subconsulta.
- > Tu consulta sin el parametro WHERE funcionara exactamente igual con o sin el ya que todas las filas cumplen la condicion.

**SOLUCION**
La manera mas sencilla de hacer lo que tu dices es la siguiente :

```
SELECT producto,imagen 
FROM tabla
GROUP BY producto
```

Ya que por defecto obtendras todos los productos distintos y la `imagen` se mostrara la primera de casa caso ya que a la hora de hacer le `GROUP BY` se coloca la primera de ellas para no dejar el hueco en blanco

Answer (score 0):

Perdón, pero no entiendo para qué complicarse tanto. Para qué una subquery? Si tu id de producto es PK no se va a repetir y cada producto tiene su imagen...

```
select id as producto, imagen
from imagenes
order by producto;
```

Answer (score 0):

Si no te importa cuál sea la imagen, lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
select distinct producto from imagenes
```

Answer (score -1):

La solución es esta SQL 2008 :

Por ejemplo:

```
ruc                    clientes
20124512121            madedera los alpes sa 
20124512121            madedera  los alpe sa
20124512121            madedera los  alpe sa
20154251251            maria prado
20154251251            prado maria
```

Allí hay 2 RUC únicos sin embargo fueron creados con distintos RS la solución, lo normal es tener los dos RUC y agarrar la primera razón social y se hace de esta manera :

tabla : clientes
campos : ruccliente,rscliente

```
select  o.* from (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ruccliente ORDER BY ruccliente DESC) AS fila,ruccliente, rscliente FROM TablaTemporalCli2) as o WHERE o.FILA < 2
```

lo que hace es :

```
fila  ruc                    clientes
1     20124512121            madedera los alpes sa 
2     20124512121            madedera  los alpe sa
3     20124512121            madedera los  alpe sa
1     20154251251            maria prado
2     20154251251            prado maria
```

y con esta condición `o.FILA < 2` solo agarra la primera fila