# ¿Cómo usar Distinct en una consulta para Laravel?

Tags: laravel, querybuilder

Tengo dos tablas unidas con un Join y estoy intentando eliminar del conteo los rif repetidos, creo que debería aplicar el distinct para el rif ya que son los datos que no quiero que se repitan.

he intentado con esto y me hace el conteo pero no me ha eliminado los rif repetidos

```
$av2 = DB::table('incidencias')
    ->join('clientes_incid', 'clientes_incid.rif', '=', 'incidencias.rif')
    ->select(DB::raw('DISTINCT(rif)'))
    ->select(DB::raw('count(cat_cliente) as av2'), 'cat_cliente')
    ->whereIn('cat_cliente', ['AV'])
    ->groupBy('cat_cliente')
    ->get();
```

¿Qué puedo hacer en este caso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agregas asi, antes del get():

```
$av2 = DB::table('incidencias')
->join('clientes_incid', 'clientes_incid.rif', '=', 'incidencias.rif')
->select(DB::raw('count(cat_cliente) as av2'), 'cat_cliente')
->whereIn('cat_cliente', ['AV'])
->groupBy('cat_cliente')
->distinct()
->get();
```

Comment: ya lo habia intentado de esa manera tambien, pero no me ha funcionado

Comment: Entonces posiblemente pueda ser la consulta sql que estas haciendo, al usar un count en una consulta sql el distinct ya no tiene sentido usarlo si tiene datos repetidos

Comment: si puede usarse el count en una consulta sql, en esta consulta lo pude hacer $incidencias2 = DB::table('incidencias')
    ->count(DB::raw('DISTINCT(rif)'));

Comment: mi priblema es que no logro hacerlo en este caso con el rif.. alguna otra sugerencia?

Comment: Por lo que entiendo, quieres hacer distinct a una sola columna. Si un caso es asi lo que primero tendrias que hacer seria una sub consulta con esa columna y de ahi unirlos con los demas con mas consultas, seria mejor que lo conviertas en un procedimiento almacenado. Si un caso es eso

Comment: si, quiero hacer solamente un distinct en la columna rif... tienes razón.. no quiero hacerlo para la columna cat_cliente, pero no hacer como hacer una subconsulta

Comment: Guiate de esta pregunta sobre el tema que necesitas https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/93139/hacer-un-distinct-solo-en-una-columna  y si es que no entiendes muy bien, creas otra pregunta con tu consulta sql que tienes y pides lo que necesites. Despues de que te ayuden esa consulta lo conviertes en un procedimiento almacenado y asi lo usarias en laravel

Comment: si amigo... ya filtre la data repetida de rif de esta manera $incidencias2 = DB::table('incidencias')
    ->count(DB::raw('DISTINCT(rif)'));

Comment: ahora quisiera de esa consulta ya hecha hacer el conteo por roles como me lo has indicado tu... pero no se como invocar esa consulta que ya hice en una nueva consulta